# Remove numbers (strip numeric characters) from the string variable

Tags: bash, shell, string

I want to strip all numeric characters from a String variable, eg from:

```
VARIABLE=qwe123rty567
```

to:

```
echo $VARIABLE
> qwerty
```

I've searched many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724531/how-to-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-bash) but they either use sed to output to file/file names, or output to echo. I was not able to get it working with because of the white space:

```
VARIABLE=$VARIABLE | sed 's/[0-9]*//g'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `bash`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${VARIABLE//[[:digit:]]/}"
qwerty
```

`[:digit:]` can contain other characters than 0 to 9 depend on your locale. If you want only to remove 0 to 9, use `C` locale instead.

Comment: Note: depending on your locale, `[:digit:]` might contain more or less than you would expect it to. If you only want the numbers 0 to 9, use `LC_COLLATE=C` and `[0-9]`.

Comment: @ChrisDown: Yes, the question asked for numeric characters, not 0 to 9, so I used `[:digit:]` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: Yeah, it's good for the question asked. It's not uncommon for Westerners to assume that `[;digit:] == [0-9]` though, so worth mentioning the pitfalls :-)

Answer (score 11):

For variety, here's methods using

`tr`:

```
VARIABLE=$(printf '%s' "$VARIABLE" | tr -d '0123456789')
```

`sed`:

```
VARIABLE=$(printf '%s' "$VARIABLE" | sed 's/[0-9]//g')
```

Bash expansion, by far the most terse:

```
VARIABLE=${VARIABLE//[0-9]/}
```

and finally Bash expansion again, this time using the `[[:digit:]]` character class.

```
VARIABLE=${VARIABLE//[[:digit:]]/}
```

Note that (as others have pointed out) `[[:digit:]]`,  *should* cover anything defined as a digit in your locale.

Comment: Where can I find docs for `//.../`? Is it a normal regex? I tried `//[0-9]{2}\$/` for two numbers at the end, to no success.

Comment: It's part of the bash variable expansion syntax, not Regexp.  It means replace all matches.

Answer (score 3):

```
VARIABLE=qwe123rty567
IFS=0123456789
set -f # Disable glob
printf %s $VARIABLE
```

---

```
qwerty
```

further manipulation is possible.

```
VARIABLE=qwe123rty567
IFS=0123456789
set -f # Disable glob
set -- $VARIABLE
IFS=;   VARIABLE=$*
printf "replaced $# numbers in \$VARIABLE. RESULT:\t%s\n" "$*"
```

---

```
replaced 6 numbers in $VARIABLE. RESULT:    qwerty
```

Comment: hmm, my variable becomes "qwe   rty" with 3 spaces in the middle and 3 at the end

Comment: @George - you're probably using `echo` which replaces nulls with spaces - like `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

White space (actually, failure to quote your variables) was only part of the problem.

You can't just pipe a variable through `sed` like that, it doesn't work.  More precisely, it doesn't pipe the value of "$VARIABLE" through `sed`, the shell will try to execute the value of "$VARIABLE" and pipe the output of that through `sed`.  BTW, this is not a bug - this is useful if $VARIABLE happens to contain a valid command like `ls` or `rsync` or whatever.

Also, if you want to assign the ouput of a command or pipeline to a variable, you need to surround that command/pipeline with `$()`.

So, to modify a variable with `sed`, you need to do something like this:

```
VARIABLE=$(printf '%s' "$VARIABLE" | sed 's/[0-9]*//g')
```

You could use `echo` there instead of `printf` but echo will interpret and act on certain character sequences in $VARIABLE (e.g. `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, etc), while `printf` won't.  You'll run across a lot of examples using `echo`...replace them with `printf '%s'`, it's much safer.

Comment: Is there any real reason to single quote the `%s` ?

Comment: @wildcard.  `%s` by itself, no.  more complicated format strings should be  quoted, though, so it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: there was no failure to quote any variables - everything was quoted just fine. and *white-space* isn't even involved *(and rarely actually is)*. i know the asker mentions it as a possible source of whatever the issue was, but it probably isn't helpful to encourage wrongful assumptions. your command substitution will strip *white-space* from the tail of whatever is in `$VARIABLE`, though.

Comment: and you're making that judgement on one made up example of `VARIABLE=qwe123rty567`? OK, right.  I made my assessment ("failure to quote your variables") on the basis of none of the OP's examples having quotes around the variables, and the fact that he mentioned white-space as being a problem.